# Altec Lansing VS4121: Dismantling the satellite speaker

Tags: speakers

Does anyone know how to dismantle the satellite speakers to a VS4121? I need to replace the coaxial cable, and I can't find any screws to unscrew. I've managed to pry off the speaker grill, but not much further. I can see an area where I can insert a flat head screwdriver, but it doesn't look like it can be used to pry this thing apart. I am a little worried that I might damage this thing if I make an attempt.

And of course, Altec Lansing doesn't have any service manuals on the web, just the install guides.

Images, which may help: https://i.stack.imgur.com/19GiX.jpg

Comment: Maybe someone here can help if you post clear snapshots of what the innards look like.

Comment: Can't get to the innards; however, I will post multiple images of the outside, in case someone can figure it out.